# How do I document that a PDF file on my webpage is opened by a customer?

Tags: jsp, servlets, pdf

I have a secure website where customers logs in to view documents that they need. These documents are mostly PDF files in a bunch of different directories (i.e. Documents/2013 for all the 2013 versions of the files). In my current application, after the customer logs in, they click on the document they want to see and it opens in a different browser page. They can then save or print it as they wish.

I would like to be able to log the fact that the customer has opened a file.

My current application merely shows the hyperlink of the PDF document which the customer can click. I am running Apache/Tomcat and java servlets.

On my session parameters, I have saved the customer id and I also have a logger servlet which I use to document that the customer has logged on and what different web pages they go to.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot exactly detect if customer has opened the file, you can detect upto the point where someone has downloaded that file from your server

By configuring a request `Filter` filtering those requests and triggering some action when the response gets committed for that request

Comment: I understand that is what I need to do. My problem is that I don't know how to do that. I can pass the file name to a jsp page, then I can log that action, but then how do I display the PDF document at that point?

Comment: You need ServletFilter

Answer (score 0):

You could use a open source viewer like PDFJS or FlexPaper (urls below). They both have easy ways of displaying PDF documents so that you can monitor which pages people view. To really make sure you would need to set up a page that handles all PDF requests and then redirect all url requests to this url. This could be done using a filter in Apache

[FlexPaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com)

[PDFJS](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)